# ui-query menu and submenu elements issues (cupertino theme)

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I am new to jquery-ui and have 2 questions for ui-menu.

Q1: ui-header for only "MEAN TOTAL SWELL DIRECTION (26 characters long) shows as one line but when mouse hovers over it splits into 2 lines.

Q2: when submenu e.g. SIGNIFICANT WAVE HEIGHT => ft is clicked neither submenu nor main menu element stays highlighted making it impossible to see which element was selected before submitting the form.  Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks

```html
<style>
  .ui-menu {
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 60%;
  }

  .ui-widget-header { padding: 0.2em; }
  ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-style: normal;
  }
  a {
        text-decoration: none;
  }
</style> 
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Comment: Providing more of your code would be helpful, i.e. the JS and HTML.  The one thing I can tell you is that if text wraps it's because it no longer fits in its container.  Either make its container bigger, or if its fluid add "whitespace: nowrap" to the css of the container.

Comment: I found a solution to Q1 already.  Thank you.

Comment: However Q2 remains un answered.  The ui menu is part of a form, I can see item in submenu highlighted when I select it and everything works like a charm when I submit the form.  However, the highlight in the submenu item disappear as soon as I fill the next field. Is there any way to keep the selected item highlighted all the time until form is submitted? The other fields in the form are regular <select> elements with lists of items to choose from.